# Coveo Facet View only showing up 2 Tags instead of all

Tags: content-search, coveo

​I have created 4 tags in Sitecore at `Sitecore/System/Settings/Buckets/TagRepository`. I have added Coveo Facet View rendering on the page and selected `Tags` field in the properties. It is only showing up 2 tags.

My Environment

- Sitecore version 8.2 update 2
- Coveo Cloud Free trial
- Coveo for Sitecore 4.0

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are another two tag assigned to some items?

Comment: @ArtsemPrashkovich Yes

Comment: Do you see those items in the search results?

Comment: @ArtsemPrashkovich Yes.Even if I browse by those tags in content editor, I can see all records with all tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values shown in facets depend on what is indexed and what is currently filtered in the search interface.

We are not *directly* using the tag repository, you need to index content that has these tags.

There are many reasons as to why it would *not* show some values, here are some things to validate:

1. Not indexed at all

   1. Items with your tags have not been reindexed with their new tag for some reason. => Reindex
   2. Items that do contain those tags are not in the crawled root. => Change the crawlers
2. Security

   1. Your public identity does not have access to those documents. => Validate the security and adjust as needed.
3. Items that have those tags are not returned in the results

   1. By default, Coveo for Sitecore shows only items that has a layout, with the current language and latest version => Remove those filters and see if they show up, or simply go in the Cloud Administration Console and test some custom queries.
   2. Other custom filters added to the `aq` part of the query => Validate anything custom and see if they interfere.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that everything is published and indexed.

Only the facets that apply to the items in the current result set will be displayed.

This is done to prevent applying facets that will result in an empty result set.

Comment: Thanks! this is indeed depends on current search results and properly indexed items.